# One website won't refresh

Tags: windows-7, browser-cache

I have a problem with only one website that won't refresh no matter what I do. I've tried deleting cache, cookies etc.

I guess something is wrong with my computer because everyone else sees the updated version of that website.

Comment: What you mean by "updated version": new design or content?

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried restarting your router?** This can sometimes fix the issue. Also note that some websites (like youtube) don't update their layout for all users at the same time. Probably to find bugs etc they release their design to a small number of people first and then release the update to the rest of the world. Also there are a few more possible scenario:

1) You have a firewall

2) You have a virus

3) Your ISP blocks the website update for one reason or another.

Comment: No, no, and no. Other than the point about controlled releasing (such as what Youtube, Facebook, and other large websites do), this is a bunch of misinformation.

Comment: 1) Firewalls would reject the connection completely, and the user wouldn't be able to connect (the browser would report an error)
2) Viruses, while possible, are incredibly unlikely (*"It's not working; must be a virus!"*)
3) See #1; the connection would be blocked. Browser caching doesn't work like this and just silently swallow errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a website that you've built - if it's CSS-related, try adding a parameter to the CSS links to force the browser to fetch new versions of the CSS files, e.g. `/Content/style.css?v=1` - it's not ideal but it will force the browser to reload the stylesheets